# How to open port via SSH tunnel?

Tags: linux, ssh, port-forwarding, ssh-tunnel

There is a system B with the following open servers: I have a web server listening on port 80 and a ssh server listening on 22. However, only port 22 is publicly available. Now, I would like to create some kind of tunnel, so that I can access B:80 from A. However, my client computer A that would like to connect to the system B is not publicly open, either.

So, all I have is a client computer A from where I would like to access the server B and, there, an open port 22. On A, no port is open or can be opened.

What (I think) I would need is to open locally (on A) some port that connects in some way through port 22 of B to port 80 on B.

Is this possibly without using any man-in-the-middle open servers with multiple ports?

Comment: I changed the title and removed the word "reverse". In SSH context it usually means remote port forwarding (`-R` option). If you needed to connect from `B` to `A` while having SSH access from `A` to `B`, then it would require a *reverse* tunnel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Note: Jakuje answered while I was composing my answer. It's more elaborate from the start, so I'm posting it anyway.)

---

If I get you right, all you need is to forward a local port through SSH. I assume you have SSH access to `B`.

Linux command to run on `A`:

```
ssh -NL 2345:127.0.0.1:80 B
```

Now you can connect to the port `2345` on `A` and it should be equivalent to connecting to the `80` port on `B` from the `B` itself.

Few remarks:

- `-N` causes `ssh` not to execute a command on the remote (`B`) side; perfect for port forwarding.
- The number `2345` is arbitrarily chosen; it may be any number from `1024` to `65535` (binding to a port lower than `1024` requires root access usually). If you happen to hit the already occupied port, then try another number.
- The `127.0.0.1` address I used requires your web server on `B` to listen on the `loopback` interface. If it listens on some other address(es) only, use it instead. This address should be a valid address of your server as seen from within the system `B`. It doesn't matter at all what this address means to `A` nor if it means something in the first place.
- If you need computer `C` to connect to the `2345` forwarded port on `A` then you should get familiar with `ssh -g` option. Read `man ssh`.

Comment: And what about the case when a gateway server is used?

Answer (score 2):

Use local port forwarding:

```
ssh -L 80:localhost:80 B
```

and then connect to `localhost:80`. The connection will be forwarded to the `B`'s port 80

Comment: great answer that works, thank you! Kamil's is more elaborate though, which is why I give him/her the mark