# ssh forward to TCP

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel, sshd

I have a particular user case: I want that any SSH connection from a specific user or port is redirected to a local TCP port, in a transparent way.

So far I try some port forwarding but require the CLIENT to add some special tags; I tryed to play a bit with different variant of -L and -R option without success.

some variant I tried are (local TCP service is 12345, I want the client to connect on SSH on 4321)

```
ssh -L 12345:localhost:4321 localhost
ssh -R 12345:localhost:4321 localhost
```

On the server SSH, I enabled TCP forwarding and GatewayPorts to client specified

I want to ssh on my machine using a custom user/port (but not custom options) and be able to communicate directly and transparently with a specific TCP service running on the machine. The communication is binary, so transparent communication is important.

To be cleaner: the client uses SSH to connect to a server and get data from a TCP socket running locally to the server

Comment: Please include a question... and an explanation / description of what you're actually trying to do would be helpful too.

Comment: Port forwarding via SSH involves four computers in general: (1) a client that starts `ssh`, (2) a server that listens with `sshd`, (3) a target to reach through the tunnel, (4) a computer that uses the tunnel to reach the target. In some circumstances some of them may be the same host, so there may be three or two real computers involved, or even one if your goal is cumbersome enough. And there's local or remote forwarding, depending on whether (4) connects to (1) or (2). Your question is unclear but your overuse of `localhost` seems close to this cumbersome one-computer idea. Please clarify.

Comment: "In a transparent way." - I am guessing when you say "transparent way" you mean, you want to forward secure SSH traffic, to an insecure port.  is that correct?

Comment: @Ramhound there are different layer of transaprency i need: SSH to TCP, as you said, but also in the communication: i could create a user with netcat/telnet as shell, but those program respond to special character thus is not transparent for the binary data.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski please note i have full control over SSHD too, as demonstrated by enabling some flag like TCPForwarding.

Also i managed to use a 3 PC configuration with the R flag (basically using a server as "brooker"), so your teory must be false somewhere.

My goal is to use SSH from client to access TCP on server. 2 pc.

Comment: Check if this question and answer helps: [*How to open port via SSH tunnel?*](https://superuser.com/q/1213886/432690) Also note how clear the question is while specifying what machine acts in which role: `A` is (1) and (4), `B` is (2) and (3) in terms of my previous comment. This is what your question is lacking. The `ssh` commands you tried suggest you want a single machine in roles (1), (2) and (3); this doesn't exactly correspond to your comment above though. Using the same host as (1) and (2) is quite peculiar, hence my initial doubts.