# Remote router access via port forwarding

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding

Configuration:
Note the ips used are made up.

Cable Modem (no internal router):  ext IP:  111.222.212.121

Router web interface: 10.0.0.1

Internal Server (no GUI): 10.0.0.10

Port forwarding is setup on the router so that;
I can SSH to 111.222.212.121 and reach Server (no GUI) 10.0.0.10

No problem so far….

I want to access the Router web interface 10.0.0.1 remotely. The router web interface is only accessible on the LAN.  Possible from 10.0.0.10, but it has no GUI or Browser. Can I setup port forwarding on 10.0.0.10 to access 10.0.0.1 remotely? Also note Telnet/SSH to the router is disabled.

I am using a MacBook Pro remotely and I do not have physical access to the remote hardware (Modem, Router, Server)

What are my options?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to open port via SSH tunnel?](https://superuser.com/questions/1213886/how-to-open-port-via-ssh-tunnel) To do so, a _local_ port forward needs to be configured within the SSH client. If using PuTTY, it's configured under _Connection_ → _SSH_ → _Tunnels_ _(e.g. L10000 10.0.0.1:443)_